# Is there a clever way to determine negative area of an integral?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Given some continuous, integratable function f(x) that has only positive area over a range from x1 to x2...is there a way to determine the negative area of the integral of f(x) - c (from x1 to x2), where c is some number?

Is there a way to do this without knowing the zeros of f(x) -c?

Answer (score 0):

Well you could integrate $(f-|f|)/2$ (the negative part of the function), but it depends on $f$ if this leads to anything nice.

Comment: In this case f is not nice...it is a Fourier Series.